# Loading image from URL in actionscript 3 not completing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am attempting to make an app in which you can load an image file from your computer or from a URL. I have the computer file part working fine, but am having an issue when I'm trying to load an image from a URL.

Here is the code:

```
public function loadNetImage(): void {
 if (urlFile.text != "")
 {
   loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
   loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError); 
   loader.addEventListener( HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, handleHttpStatus); 
   loader.addEventListener( SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleSecurityError);
   try {
     var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlFile.text);
     loader.load(request);
   }
   catch (e:Error)
  {
     trace(e);
  }
 }
}
```

The problem: After the load is requested, it doesn't call any of my events. There are no errors and there is no loading. You can see from this code a snippet of things I've tried to see if there is an error.

urlFile.text is a string returning from my flex textInput. I put in a hard coded string instead of the urlFile.text and that did not work. I changed to a URLLoader instead of a base Loader, and that sort of worked (it completed the load) but I couldn't do the image manipulation afterwards that I wanted to do, and I saw in other posts here that a Loader is the correct thing to be using.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's probably something small, but I am rather frustrated by it at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _loader_completeHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, _loader_errorHandler);
```

and so on.

Events dispatched from `contentLoaderInfo` (which is `flash.display.LoaderInfo`) property of `Loader`.

See

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary

Comment: Argghhhh! I won't tell you how much time I wasted on this particular problem. :)  Thank you, this totally fixed the problem!